# How to transform and filter a MARC21-xml into csv?

Tags: xml, xslt, marc

I have xml file according to MARC21-format which looks like this:

(it is reduced to necessary tags, the file has many `records` which I reduced just to one)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<record>
  <controlfield tag="001">EntryID01</controlfield>
  <datafield tag="100" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="0">PubID01</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Lastname01, Firstname01</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="0">PubID02</subfield>
    <subfield code="a">Lastname02, Firstname02</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield tag="700" ind1="1" ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="a">Lastname03, Firstname03</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
</collection>
```

I would like to get a csv which has the following order/output.

```
Lastname01, Firstname01 | PubID01 | EntryID01
Lastname02, Firstname02 | PubID02 | EntryID01
Lastname03, Firstname03 | NOPUBID | EntryID01
```

Not all datafields have the information for PubID (`subfield code="0"`), if there is no PubID given it should be written "NOPUBID" instead.

My attempt was using `xsltproc` with this `xsl`:
(I was trying to get the data from `tag=100` first; but I need it also from `tag=700`)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
exclude-result-prefixes="marc">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="marc:controlfield[@tag=001]">
            <xsl:value-of select="controlfield"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="marc:datafield[@tag=100]">
        <xsl:for-each select="record/datafield">
            <xsl:value-of select="controlfield"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I fail desperatly. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well, injecting `NOPUBID` is something I would consider as a pre-processing or separate step. Are you able to run two stylesheets? Are you restricted to xsltproc and XSLT 1.0?

Comment: I could do two stylesheets and I would use anything that works with CLI and within bash etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/marc:collection">
    <xsl:for-each select="marc:record">
        <xsl:variable name="control" select="marc:controlfield[@tag='001']" />
        <xsl:for-each select="marc:datafield[@tag='100' or @tag='700']">
            <xsl:value-of select="marc:subfield[@code='a']"/>
            <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
            <xsl:variable name="pub" select="marc:subfield[@code='0']"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$pub">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$pub"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>NOPUBID</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:text> | </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$control"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your solution works great with the data I provided, but only thouse fields with `tag=100` or `tag=700` should be considered. I can easily add this with e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="marc:datafield[@tag='100']">` and do another `for-each-loop` for `tag=700`. Or is there a possibility to add a condition, like `<xsl:for-each select="marc:datafield[@tag='100'] OR marc:datafield[@tag='700'">` ?

Comment: `<xsl:for-each select="marc:datafield[@tag='100' or @tag='700']">` I have added this to my answer.

Comment: my assumption was quite close ... :-) thanks alot for the quick help!